# JOIN and SUM values from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sum

I have 3 tables like the tables below

tbl_GasExpense

```
GID  |  Gas_Expense  | Date_Occured
-----------------------------------
1   |  400          | 11/30/2014
2   |  500          | 11/30/2014
3   |  300          | 11/30/2014
```

tbl_Food Expense

```
FID  |  Food_Expense | Date_Occured
-----------------------------------
1   |  450          | 11/30/2014
2   |  250          | 11/30/2014
3   |  390          | 11/30/2014
```

tbl_Drink Expense

```
DID  |  Drink_Expense | Date_Occured
-----------------------------------
1   |  150          | 11/30/2014
2   |  250          | 11/30/2014
3   |  360          | 11/30/2014
```

and with those tables above, I want an output like this.

```
ID  |  Gas_Sum  |  Food_Sum  |  Drink_Sum  | Date_Occured
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   |    1200   |    1090    |    760      | 11/30/2014
```

The values of the three tables from which are dated 11/30/2014 are summed in table four.
Using the IDs from the first three tables as foreign keys in the table 4 to establish a relation. Gas_Sum is a mask for GID, Food_Sum for FID, Drink_Sum for DID.

Comment: you are summing values of all rows and presenting it against id 1? so does id matter?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I already have my answer now after several trial and errors
.. it is something like this. but this is on my own code

```
SELECT o.eh_ID, SUM(o.others_amt) as 'OTHERS SUM'
FROM tbl_Others o
INNER JOIN tbl_ExpenseHead hd ON hd.eh_ID = o.eh_ID
GROUP BY o.eh_ID
```